# Why mysql server ignore cancel while deleting user

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I created user called "Try" where global privileges I set it to all privileges

[image: users table]

and once I checked it and delete it
with "Drop the databases that have the same names as the users." checkbox checked

[image: check box shown]

and go ahead click "go"
I get this pop up

[image: warning]

and click on "OK" as soon as I clicked I get the second warning pop up which is the following

[image: second warning]

and then click on cancel but process was not canceled because the user was removed and i got the success message which is the following

[image: success pop up]

so I really wanna know that if there is any further configuration for that and if not why this happen or if it is unique problem for me only
thanks in advanced

Comment: They're two separate confirmations. You said yes to the first one, so it did that step. You said no to the second one, so it didn't do that step. It did exactly what you told it to do.

Comment: yes and I wanna know why

Comment: I explained why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "Cancel" feature in MySQL. MySQL only executes SQL queries written in SQL language.

PHPMyAdmin is a convenience tool to execute SQL queries on MySQL server. When you perform an operation in PHPMyAdmin, it will execute one or more SQL queries on the server.

In this particular case, it first executes the `DROP USER` SQL query, and then shows a confirmation if you really want to `DROP DATABASE`.

There is no transaction here, so each step is executed individually.